# VM as a device in domain XML

Tags: libvirt

I'm a libvirt newbie. Is it possible to create two VMs in one domain definition? The second VM is like a slave device. The connection between the slave and master is through a dedicated Ethernet port.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's about the "domain" meaning: It is a SEPARATE resource set for a dedicated VM, so create two domains, and a private virtual network just for them.